# Generate Contact File (.vcf) from WordPress Post Data?

Tags: wordpress, vcf-vcard

After creating new post I need to generate and store the .vcf file in storage. I don't know how I can do this after post save. Didn't find help to develop such function. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "store the .vcf file in storage"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

On "save_post" hook you can write function. That will create .vcf file with the name of post_title at specified directory.

```
function my_project_create_vCard( $post_id ) {
    $vpost = get_post($post->ID);
    $filename = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$vpost->post_title)).".vcf";
    header('Content-type: text/x-vcard; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    $data=null;
    $data.="BEGIN:VCARD\n";
    $data.="VERSION:2.1\n";
    $data.="FN:".$vpost->post_title."\n"; // get post title
    $data.="EMAIL:" .get_field('email',$vpost->ID)."\n";  // get acf field value
    $data.="END:VCARD";
    $filePath = get_template_directory()."/".$filename; // you can specify path here where you want to store file.
    $file = fopen($filePath,"w");
    fwrite($file,$data);
    fclose($file);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_create_vCard' );
```

Comment: where this file is saved? location?

Comment: you can add this function to your function.php file of your theme or create a simple custom plugin and activate it.